# Complex power function for $c \neq 0$ is $c^z := e^{z \log c}$. If $c$ is Euler's number, is the definition consistent with $e^z := e^xe^{iy}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The way I have seen the complex power function defined is as follows: for any complex number $c \neq 0$
$$
c^z := e^{z \log c}.
$$
In this definition, the symbol $e^w$ is defined via Eulers formula, writing $w = u +iv$
$$
e^{w} := e^u e^{iv} = e^u \cos v + ie^u \sin v
$$
where $e^u$ ($u$ is a real number) is the usual exponential function from calculus. Also, the complex logarithm is defined to be
$$
\log z : = \ln |z| + i \arg z.
$$

*If we take $c$ to be Euler's number, is the definition of the power function consistent with the definition of the complex exponential $e^z := e^xe^{iy}$?*

**In this question, $\arg z = \text{Arg } z +2k\pi, \ k\in \mathbb{Z}$ where $\text{Arg } z$ is the principal argument of $z$.**

Comment: Well, $\log e = 1$.

Comment: I think $\log e = \ln|e| + i\arg e = 1 + 2k\pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\operatorname{arg} e = 2k\pi$, where $k$ is the *unique* integer such that $2k\pi \in [-\pi,\pi)$, that is, $k=0$.

Comment: No, I am not talking about the principal argument. These are multiple-valued functions.

Comment: $\log$ is a *function*, and is common to use the principal branch for this.

Comment: It is a multiple-valued function until you choose a branch. In the context of the question, I am not asking about a specific branch.